# free memory used to return value in C

Tags: c, memory-management, return, malloc, free

I have a function that calls another function which creates a unique ID and returns it as a string by malloc().

my question is how do I free the memory once outside the function? or what is the better way to do what I would like to do.

my function that asks for the ID:

```
void addCustomer(TennisStoreType* ts){

   CustomerNodePtr newcustdata;
   int datapos = 0;

   newcustdata = malloc(sizeof(CustomerNodeType));

   while (datapos <= CUSTDATA_POSITIONS) {

      char userinput[BUFFER_SIZE];

      switch (datapos) {
         case 0:
            strcpy(newcustdata->custID, createCustID(ts));
            break;
   }
}
```

the function that returns uniqueID:

```
char* createCustID(TennisStoreType* ts) {

   char *custID;

   custID = (char *)malloc(CUSTID_LEN + 1 * sizeof(char));

   if (ts->customerCount + 1 >= FOURDIGITS) {
      sprintf(custID, "C%i\n", ts->customerCount + 1);

   } else if (ts->customerCount + 1 >= THREEDIGITS){
      sprintf(custID, "C0%i\n", ts->customerCount + 1);

   } else if (ts->customerCount + 1 >= TWODIGITS) {
      sprintf(custID, "C00%i\n", ts->customerCount + 1);

   } else {
      sprintf(custID, "C000%i\n", ts->customerCount + 1);
   }

   return custID;
}
```

so how would I go about freeing the string that has been copied to newcustdata->custID? do I even need to? or is there a better way to go about doing this?

thanks in advance.

Comment: `sprintf(custID, "C%04d\n", ts->customerCount+1);` is what you want. And your `strcpy(newcustdata->custID, createCustID(ts));` in the calling function leaks memory.

Comment: Instead of allocating memory, then copying, just pass the final pointer into the function and sprint directly to it.

Comment: the string creations are working perfectly right now, what will that do that my current set up wont?

Comment: `strcpy(newcustdata->custID, createCustID(ts));` as `createCustID(ts)` returns a dynamic allocation address, this code is a recipe for leaking memory. Not knowing anything else about the posted code and an inability to compile+run it thusly due to incomplete/unknown info, not much more to say about it, as we can't even confirm `strcpy` is even *correct* in that situation, though the memory leak is inarguable regardless.

Comment: the problem with that caveman is I want to use this function for other things that doesn't require a passed in string

Comment: strcpy works fine but yes I am trying to remove the memory leak by freeing it after I store it in newcustdata->custID, I just have no idea how to do it or even if it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can eliminate that function entirely. The line

```
strcpy(newcustdata->custID, createCustID(ts));
```

can simply be written as

```
sprintf( newcustdata->custID, "C%04d", ts->customerCount + 1 );
```

provided, of course that `custID` is an array of at least 6 characters, e.g.

```
char custID[8];
```

Notes:

1. I typically round `char` array sizes up to multiples of 8, since structure
   padding will waste the bytes anyways.
2. I removed the `\n` since it doesn't seem right to have a newline
   character in a unique ID, but of course you can add it back in.

---

If you really like that function, and want to keep it, then replace

```
switch (datapos) {
   case 0:
      strcpy(newcustdata->custID, createCustID(ts));
      break;
}
```

with this

```
char *temp;
switch (datapos) {
   case 0:
      temp = createCustID(ts);
      strcpy(newcustdata->custID, temp);
      free( temp );
      break;
}
```

That will free up the memory after the copy.

Comment: thanks that is definitely a solution I can incorporate that would work for me, however I am still wondering if it is possible to free() the data malloc() in a different function that has been removed or not.

Comment: @RoryThoman updated the answer to show how to free the memory.

Comment: using the flags -ansi -Wall -pedantic this doesn't work as you can't create a variable right after a goto: (which is what a switch statment does) but I understand what you are saying so I can work around it. thanks.

Comment: @RoryThoman Yup, sorry, didn't try to compile it. You're right though, `temp` needs to be declared before the `switch` statement.

Comment: this definitly helped me understand what I can do to fix it in multiple ways, accepted as the answer because of this, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your createCustID() function is going to allocate some memory, then return it to the caller, by returning the pointer it got from malloc().

The calling routine, when it is done with the structure, can (and must) free the memory by passing that same pointer to free().

In your example, you need to expand the logic in addCustomer() to retain the pointer it received from createCustID() long enough to (1) test that it is not null, (2) copy the contents locally if needed, and (3) free the received block.

As others have pointed out, you might find it more efficient to just build the received block into the data structure you are assembling, rather than making a copy of it.  However, you would still need to free the block as part of your logic for disposing the larger data structure.

You need to plan your code paths carefully with this type of code, so that you always know who "owns" the allocated block, and is responsible for freeing it when it is no longer needed.

Also, you must *always* check the return value of malloc() against null.  If malloc fails to give you the memory you asked for, you need to handle the error appropriately; not just forge ahead writing data into the null pointer.

Comment: yes I understand what is going on, this is the complete or finished code I am still working on it and am well aware that I will need to check malloc against NULL. but that being said you didn't really explain what I can do about this current situation to avoid/ fix the memory leak.

Comment: Declare a temporary pointer to hold the function's return value; use it to copy from; then free it (as in user3386109's answer)